# AWS InvalidSignatureException, Signature expired when running from docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, time

I'm experiencing an issue where I am developing a program within a docker container, and out of nowhere I seem to be getting an issue with invalid signatures. The following exception is raised when I attempt to retrieve resources from AWS Secrets Manager (I do not believe the specific AWS service is relevant to the issue):

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred
>   (InvalidSignatureException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation:
>   Signature expired: 20200505T192909Z is now earlier than
>   20200506T151410Z (20200506T151910Z - 5 min.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This exception is known to happen when the client system's clock is out of sync with the clock AWS is synced with.

To check the time of this container, I paused my program at a break point and checked the current time. Sure enough, it was off from the actual time!

## First thing to check:

The first thing to check is your local system's time. If it's off, re-sync it and try again. **That *should* fix the problem.**

1. This can be done on unix-like systems by using [`ntpd`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ntpd).
2. Windows users can go to Start -> Settings -> Time & Language -> Date & Time -> **Synchronize your clock**

## Docker Desktop

**Users of Docker Desktop might still get the same error despite their local machine's time being synced.**

While it's true that docker containers will have synced time with their host, it is important to note that Docker Desktop runs a virtual machine for docker. With that said, *the mac or windows machine is NOT the host, the VM is.* This is the problem I was having. My windows desktop had a synced and up to date date/time, but the Docker Desktop VM was the problem.

***I was able to resolve this issue by restarting Docker Desktop.***

Comment: Thanks for this answer - the only thing that worked was restarting docker desktop.

Comment: Thanks, for centos users  on EC2 `sudo service chronyd restart`

Comment: chrony service setup link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html#configure-amazon-time-service-ubuntu

Comment: Docker — or in my case, Finch — was the problem. Restarting its vm fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Used WSL2 i run in powershell mode admin

```
$ wsl --shutdown

$ wsl
```

And run code again!